# how to synthesize a virtual control arm from multiple historical trials with different treatment in their control arms

Tags: experiment-design, clinical-trials, synthetic-data

We want to synthesize a virtual control arm for a single arm study, and we found two trials with data available that targeting the same population. One trial used Placebo+Standard of care in the control arm, and the other trial used Standard of care alone in the control arm. Can we combine these two trials to get a larger population in the virtual control arm? Any special considerations that need to be taken care?

Answer (score 1):

The safest and most robust approach is just to ignore the trial with the design you don't seek to emulate. This is to safeguard you against making any possibly incorrect assumptions about the effect of placebo and about the homogeneity of the trials. It is in fact the later that is most dangerous. You find heterogeneity in sites, in patients, in time, in the treatment and training that the physicians have practicing at that time.

For most trial designs, at least in cancer, patients participate only because they want access to the novel therapy. If the design is open label, fewer patients participate when they realize they are receiving a control. The end result is an "inferential shift" that makes it hard to evaluate intent-to-treat effects.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion and comments!